# Bitrate 64 is not supported when Profile/Channels/SamplingRate is AACLC/2/48000

Tags: azure, audio, azure-media-services, encoder, notsupportedexception

I am using Azure standard media encoder to convert mp3 into mp4 files audio only.

What are the recommendations for encoding 64k audio?

I am getting an error:
Bitrate 64 is not supported when Profile/Channels/SamplingRate is AACLC/2/48000!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked and answered in the MSDN Forum [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a11f59d8-f43a-4014-a2ea-79144e04cfbe/problem-in-encoding-audio?forum=MediaServices).